# Full calender add dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I tries to add full calendar. First time I clicked the button and it added success. after I clear my ScheduleCalender div using jquery `empty()` method. and I re-run the full calender code. But full calender doe's not appear. At lease no content appear inside the div. Here my code. my div selector is working fine. I tested that.

```
$('#addNewTimeScheduleEntry').click(function () {
    $('#scheduleCalendar').empty();
    var scheduleYear = $('.scheduleYear').val();
    var scheduleMonth = $('.scheduleMonth').val();

    $('#scheduleCalendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: scheduleYear + '-' + scheduleMonth + '-01',
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: 'title'
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.qtip({
                content: event.description,
                style: {
                    classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow'
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'top left', // Position my top left...
                    at: 'bottom right', // at the bottom right of...
                    target: $(element) // my target
                }
            });

        },
        height: $('.panel-body').height()-50

    });

});
```

[here has full calendar link](http://fullcalendar.io/)

Here my html

```
<div class="panel-body fixed-content">
    <div class="year-month-control">
    <select class="selectpicker scheduleYear">
    </select>

    <select class="selectpicker scheduleMonth">
    </select>

        <button type="button" id="addNewTimeScheduleEntry" class="btn btn-default" id="addnewScheduleEntry"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Entry</button>
        <button type="button" id="addNewTimeScheduleEntry" class="btn btn-default" id="saveScheduleEntry" ><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>&nbsp;Save Entry</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id='scheduleCalendar'></div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you show your html

Answer (score 1):

It runs fine even after you empty the div. the only difference is that I have put it in the document ready event but I dont think that should make any difference. Here are 2 jsfiddles;
http://jsfiddle.net/2qs8tyg1/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#addNewTimeScheduleEntry').click(function () {
        $('#scheduleCalendar').empty();
        $('#scheduleCalendar').fullCalendar({});
        var scheduleYear = date.getFullYear();
        var scheduleMonth = date.getMonth();

        $('#scheduleCalendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: scheduleYear + '-' + scheduleMonth + '-01',
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: 'title'
            },
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                element.qtip({
                    content: event.description,
                    style: {
                        classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow'
                    },
                    position: {
                        my: 'top left', // Position my top left...
                        at: 'bottom right', // at the bottom right of...
                        target: $(element) // my target
                    }
                });

            },
            height: $('.panel-body').height()-50

        });

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/justinobney/uaNgR/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            viewDisplay: function(view) {
                window.location.hash = "month=" + (view.start.getMonth() + 1) + "&year=" +view.start.getFullYear();
            },
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
        });

    function setupRouting() {
        $.jsRouter.mapRoute('Month Change', 'month={month}&year={year}', MonthChanged);
    }

    function MonthChanged(args) {
        var vMonth = args.month;
        var vYear = args.year;
        console.log('event trapped:', args);
    }
        $.getScript('http://www.tasktrackr.com/js/routing.js',setupRouting);
    //jQuery.deparam.fragment()
    //$.getScript('https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/master/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js')
    });
```

Comment: For some reason it works only with Jquery version 1.7.2 or less http://jsfiddle.net/2qs8tyg1/2/. But the contents do appear in the div which the original problem was. The contents are loaded in div but the height does not get adjusted to accomodate the calendar. It only shows the calendar header and its controls.

Comment: I will see why that is so